# Laravel request()->all() doesn't get all inputs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Sending data via `POST` form. Why doesn't the controller see all of the values? I've been playing around with the validation, so even setting those to `'required'` doesn't change anything...

**Form snippet:**

```
 <form action="{{ Protocol::home() }}/offers/make" method="POST" id="sendOffer">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <!-- Price -->
            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                <label>{{ Lang::get('ads/show.lang_your_price') }}</label>
                <input type="text"  id="price_id" name="price" value="0">
                <span class="help-block">{{ Lang::get('ads/show.lang_the_amount_required') }} <b>{{ Helper::getPriceFormat($ad->price, $ad->currency) }}</b></span>
            </div>
            <!-- location -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>location label</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Andover MA" id="location_id" class="form-control" name="location_name">
            </div>
            <!-- Email Address -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>email label</label>
                <input type="email" required="" placeholder="email" id="email_name" class="form-control" name="email_name">
            </div>
            <!-- Phone -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>phone label</label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="12" placeholder="555-867-5309" id="friendNumber" class="form-control" name="phone_name">
            </div>
            <!--Time section-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>The time</label>
                <input type="time" id="time_id" name="time_name"
                       min="9:00" max="18:00" required>
            </div>
            <!-- Post ID -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>{{ Lang::get('ads/show.lang_post_id') }} (for reference)</label>
                <input type="text" readonly="" placeholder="{{ Lang::get('ads/show.lang_post_id') }}" id="postID" value="{{ $ad->ad_id }}" class="form-control" name="ad_id">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{ Lang::get('ads/show.lang_send_offer') }}</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

---

**Controller:**

```
/**
 *  Make New Offer
 */
public function make(Request $request)
{
    // Check ajax request
    if ($request->ajax()) {

            $rules = array(
            'location_name' => '',
            'email_name' => '',
            'phone_name' => '',
            'time_name' => '',
            'ad_id' => 'required'
        );
        //run rules
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // error
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg'    => __(print_r($request->all())),
            );
            return Response::json($response);
        }else{
            // Get Inputs
            $price = $request->get('price');
            $location_name  = $request->input('location_name');
            $email_name = $request->input('email_name');
            $phone_name = $request->input('phone_name');
            $time_name = $request->input('time_name');
            $ad_id = $request->input('ad_id');
            $input = $request->all();
            //let's figure it out:
            dd($input);
        // Success test
          $response = array(
          'status' => 'success',
          'msg'    => __('return/success.lang_offer_submitted'),
           );
return Response::json($response);
```

---

**Output in console (only showing price and ad_id for some reason):**

```
 array:2 [
  "price" => "0"
  "ad_id" => "1988726232"
]
```

---

**Route:**

```
// Make an Offer
Route::post('offers/make', 'Ads\OffersController@make');
```

Comment: Do the other input fields have values when you submit? Looking at your markup only `price` and `ad_id` have values.

Comment: Ya, I'm typing them in myself...that's why I'm so confused

Comment: @adam I did notice if I change the `id` of price, it goes to null.... does that mean something else is checking for the `id` somewhere? I've also tried changing the other `id`'s to match the `name` value

Comment: Hey @adam if you'd like, you can copy paste my answer and i'll mark it as correct since this comment lead to the answer

Comment: Thats ok @Petro I was confused as to why the inputs weren't coming through at all. Laravel resolves to null for inputs without values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was a result of me forgetting to include these fields in the ajax request *smh*

```
    var _root = $('#root').attr('data-root');
    var offerPrice = document.getElementById('offerPrice').value;
    var postID = document.getElementById('postID').value;
    var location_name = document.getElementById('location_name').value;
    var email_name = document.getElementById('email_name').value;
    var phone_name = document.getElementById('phone_name').value;
    var time_name = document.getElementById('time_name').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _root + '/offers/make',
        data: {
            price: offerPrice,
            ad_id: postID,
            location_name: location_name,
            email_name: email_name,
            phone_name: phone_name,
            time_name: time_name
        },
```

Comment: `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('sendOffer'));`

can save you some code and time but fields names must match your request